# Why cant I 'sudo apt-get install nfs-common'?

Tags: apt, software-installation, nfs

I am trying to install the NFS client:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
```

For a reason I don't understand, I get this response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package nfs-common is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

E: Package 'nfs-common' has no installation candidate
```

I am 98 % sure that I got that working on another machine. So, am I doing something wrong or what might cause this error?

**Edit**:
*What version of Ubuntu is this*:

```
540 $ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
```

*Updating*

```
541 $ sudo apt-get update
...
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 129.69.8.112 80]
...
... etc etc ...
```

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this?

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update`? What was the result?